# Turn a hex string into a percent encoded string in Python

Tags: python, percent-encoding

I have a string. It looks like `s = 'e6b693e6a0abe699ab'`.

I want to put a percent sign in front of every pair of characters, so `percentEncode(s) == '%e6%b6%93%e6%a0%ab%e6%99%ab'`.

What's a good way of writing `percentEncode(s)`?

(Note, I don't care that [unreserved characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters) aren't converted into ASCII.)

I can think of big verbose ways of doing this, but I want something nice and simple, and while I'm fairly new to Python, I'd be suprised if Python can't do this nicely.

Comment: Would you by any chance want to result to `s.decode('hex')`?

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ - nah, `s.decode('hex')` turns a string of 8 bit characters into the hexadecimal representation of it. I'm actually already using it to create `s`.

Comment: actually, what you describe is `s.encode('hex')`, but you answered my question whether you do need it :)

Comment: Although a standard library that does the full encoding/decoding would be even better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> ''.join( "%"+i+s[n+1] for n,i in enumerate(s)  if n%2==0 )
'%e6%b6%93%e6%a0%ab%e6%99%ab'
```

Or using re

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("(..)","%\\1",s)
'%e6%b6%93%e6%a0%ab%e6%99%ab'
```

Comment: I like the regex solution. You also found a bug in SO — before I edited it, the first method displayed as code in the JS preview, but as a quote in the server-rendered version.

Comment: Yes, the regex is best.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, you mean:

```
''.join(["%%%s" % pair for pair in [s[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(s),2)]])
```

Though probably if you're doing this for url escaping or some such, there's a library function more appropriate to your use.

Edited to add -- since everyone loves a cute itertools solution:

```
>>> from itertools import izip, cycle
>>> its = iter(s)
>>> tups = izip(cycle('%'), its, its)
>>> ''.join(''.join(t) for t in tups)
'%e6%b6%93%e6%a0%ab%e6%99%ab'
```

Comment: cycle('%') will provide the same thing, since '' are iterable.

Comment: Thanks @kevpie, incorporated this.

Answer (score 2):

On the off chance that you are doing URL-encoding manually, you might want to read this [blog post](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/10/how-escape-percent-encode-url-python/).  It explains how to do this using the standard library's [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) module's [`quote_plus`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) function.

Answer (score 1):

use a Regex to the effect of `/([0-9a-f]{2})/ig` and replace with `%\1`

Answer (score 1):

Just to be academic.

Trying to use as many iterators as possible.

```
s = 'e6b693e6a0abe699ab'

from itertools import islice, izip, cycle, chain

def percentEncode(s):
    percentChars = cycle('%')
    firstChars = islice(s,0,None, 2)
    secondChars = islice(s,1,None, 2)
    return ''.join(chain.from_iterable(izip(percentChars, firstChars, secondChars)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
     print percentEncode(s)
```

Thanks to @tcarobruce for the reminder to reuse the string iter.

```
s = 'e6b693e6a0abe699ab'

from itertools import islice, izip, cycle, chain

def percentEncode(s):
    iter_s = iter(s)
    return ''.join(chain.from_iterable(izip(cycle('%'), iter_s, iter_s)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
     print percentEncode(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on a comment of yours in the initial question, if starting from the initial string `initial_s` before its encoding into hex, you can have the result as:

```
def percent_encode(initial_s):
    return ''.join('%%%02x' % ord(c) for c in initial_s)

>>> percent_encode('hello')
'%68%65%6c%6c%6f'
```